# How to check if image is empty and will not crash the app

Tags: android

Hi when I'm clicking the post button on my android app but the image is empty the app crashes can you guys help me with this? Thanks. Here is my code. i guess the bitmap ones is the problem here but still not sure I tried like the `textUtils` on the editText but it didnt work. LOL

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(selectedPhoto).requestSize(512,512).getBitmap();
            final String encodeImage = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
            HashMap<String, String> post = new HashMap<String, String>();
            post.put("image", encodeImage);
            PostResponseAsyncTask taskUpload = new PostResponseAsyncTask(InsertActivity.this, post, new AsyncResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    if (s.contains("upload_success")) {

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Uploading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            taskUpload.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/upload1.php");
            taskUpload.setEachExceptionsHandler(new EachExceptionsHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleIOException(IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Connect to Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void handleMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void handleProtocolException(ProtocolException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Protocol Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void handleUnsupportedEncodingException(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Encoding Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong while choosing photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        HashMap postData = new HashMap();

        postData.put("image", toString());
        postData.put("txtCapacity", etCapacity.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtCarType", etCarType.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtCarModel", etCarModel.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtPrice",etPrice.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtPlateNumber", etPlateNumber.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtOwner", pref.getString("username","").toString());
        postData.put("txtFuelType", spFuelType.getSelectedItem().toString());
        postData.put("txtFrom",etFrom.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtTo", etTo.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtStatus","pending");
        postData.put("txtVerification","pending");

        PostResponseAsyncTask taskPost = new PostResponseAsyncTask(InsertActivity.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, s);
                if (s.contains("Insert Successfully")) {
                    Toast.makeText(InsertActivity.this, "Car will be verified for 2-3 days", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(InsertActivity.this, OwnerTabs.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        taskPost.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/carkila/insert.php");
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(uri);
            String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
            selectedPhoto = photoPath;
            try {
                bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512,512).getBitmap();
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong while opening gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the image is empty`?

Comment: Uh, if my `ivImage` didn't set an bitmap image. I guess. Ill post my `onActivityResult` sorry for that.

Comment: Still unclear. Do you mean `my image path equals the null string`? Do you mean `my image contains all transparent pixels`? Do you mean `my file size is 0`? Do you mean ... what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `not null` check before using bitmap. `if (bitmap != null) {  //use bitmap }`.

Comment: inside the `onClick`?

Comment: Both in `onClick` and `onActivityResult`

Comment: Wherever you use it, put this check. It ensure that the code will be executed only if bitmap has value.